# neo4j: how to query subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to select a subgraph(S) from my neo4j database and use another query on S to find if two given nodes are connected. Is there a way to write a query in neo4j ? I'm using node.js and Cypher.
EDIT:
I'm doing something similar to this, for example:

```
Match (u:User)-[:adds]->(y:Paper)-[:consistsOf]->(e:L2)-[]->(m:L3)
where u.username = 'test'
MATCH p=(m:L3)-[r:gives*1..4]->(n:L3)
...
```

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is: "yes". Perhaps if you provided a longer, more specific question, you can get a longer answer :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, you could use the WITH clause to connect the 2 MATCH statements, like this (cleaned up a little):

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'test'})-[:adds]->(y:Paper)-[:consistsOf]->(e:L2)-->(m:L3)
WITH m
MATCH p=(m)-[r:gives*1..4]->(n:L3)
...
```

The WITH clause is like RETURN, except that its purpose is to pass value(s) from one query to the next. In this case, only 'm' is being passed, and so the second MATCH will not be aware of 'u', 'y', or 'e'.

Comment: So, the node n will also come from the first query? If not, how do I make it come from the first query ?

Comment: The n node continues to come from the second MATCH statement.

Comment: Yes, that works. I was wondering if there was a way to improve performance for this case.

Comment: Try this (I'm not sure it will make any difference, but it is simpler):

MATCH (:User {username:'test'})-[:adds]->(:Paper)-[:consistsOf]->(:L2)-->(m:L3), 
p=(m)-[r:gives*1..4]->(n:L3)

Comment: From your first comment, I guess you meant that n is not a part of m, right ?Too make things more clear, I was wondering if this query would work if I wanted both m and n to be connected to user test. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this query will ensure that there is a path from user 'test' to n, through m.